# Need to compare two arrays of strings in swift checking for sameness

Tags: swift, algorithm

I am trying to write an algorithm that scores the accuracy of someones prediction. The program works as follows - a user makes 10 selections from a list of 40 names. Their selections are then compared to a list of 10 names from that 40 and they are scored for how accurate their selections are. How might I go about this? Levenshtein distance doesn't seem to work because it doesn't account for the order of a list just the presence of characters in the list itself. Any ideas? No code necessary if you want to just detail your approach but if you do provide code I am writing this algorithm in swift so feel free to stick with that. Thanks!

UPDATE:

Hey everyone thanks so much for chiming in! Everyone who posted an algorithm had a good solution so thank you. To give some more context - the array of 40 is a list of 40 names competing in a competition. Each user selects 10 names from the list in the order they think these 40 athletes will finish on the leaderboard so the actual index of their placements matter a lot because someone who predicts all 10 in reverse order of the outcome should not have the same score as someone who predicts all 10 in perfect order.

The algorithm I came up with first checks for the presence of matching names in each arrays and increments a user score by 1 if they merely predicted someone to end up in the top 10. Then, if that user predicted the correct index of the name in the array they get another point so I nest a comparison of indices. Furthermore, if a user predicts either the winner, second place or third place name correctly they are allotted an additional point to handle the edge case in which someone with 8,9 and 10 correct has the same score as someone with a perfect podium.

Let me know your thoughts on this everyone! Did I miss any edge cases?

Comment: How do you define the "accurateness" of a selection?

Comment: If you can provide more context, like an example of what you are trying to accomplish and the result you should expect. That will much easier for answering your question

Comment: If the position is relevant, then you may add a certain score for each element, according to the distance between the element in the user-made list, and the list which contains the right names (see my answer for details).

Comment: You might want to weight the picks and give them (for example) 3 points for picking the winner, 2 for picking place and 1 for picking show.

Comment: I think that the score should depend on the distance between the guessed position and the actual position. Giving a +1 doesn't discriminate between a wrong guess by 9 positions (e.g. 1st instead of 10th), and a wrong guess by one position (e.g. 2nd instead of 3rd).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Set` and `intersection` to find out how many matches there are:

```
var userSelections = ["b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "z"]
var correctResults = ["b", "a", "d", "c", "e", "f", "h", "g", "i", "j"]

let matches = Set(correctResults).intersection(userSelections).count

print("you got \(matches) of \(correctResults.count) right")

var placeMatches = 0
for i in correctResults.indices {
    if userSelections[i] == correctResults[i] {
        placeMatches += 1
    }
}

print("you placed \(placeMatches) correctly")

// Give 3 points for picking winner, 2 for place, and 1 for show
var bonus = 0

for i in 0 ..< 3 {
    if userSelections[i] == correctResults[i] {
        bonus += (3 - i)
    }
}

print("you earned \(bonus) bonus points")

print("total score = \(matches + placeMatches + bonus)")
```

> you got 9 of 10 right
>  you placed 3 correctly
>  you earned 4
>   bonus points
>  total score = 16

Answer (score -1):

Here is my suggestion: 
Let's call the right answer array A and the user array B

1. Go over array A
2. On each item search it on B array
3. If not found score will be zero else if found the score will be the gap (index on B - index on A)

The complexity is o(n^2) but since the input is 10 it's not an issue

Another suggestion: modify sort algorithm to count the number of steps it is performing, sort array A and keep the score, sort array B and compare the scores...
In theory it will reflect the "distance" but it may be depended on which sort algorithm you will use

Answer (score -1):

Let A be the array that contains the user selection, and B the array that contains the right choices. For each element of A, you check if this element is in the B array. If there is no such element, you add 0 points. If there is such element, you add *100 - D<sup>2</sup>* points, where D is the distance between the two elements (e.g. if an element is in the 5th position of the array A, and in 7th position of the array B, then the distance is 2). The total score is the sum of the score obtained for each element.